# What does $IFACE mean?

Tags: networking

I've been modifying my interfaces file and in numerous places I see the use of the keyword `$IFACE` in various contexts. I can find no mention of it in the [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/interfaces.5.html). What does this mean? Is it a keyword understood by the interfaces file or am I supposed to change it to something to tailor examples for my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IFACE` is an internal variable for `ifupdown` (`ifup` and `ifdown`), could be used in the relevant configuration file `/etc/network/interfaces` (and on files from relevant directories).

The variable `IFACE`expands to the name of the interface being processed currently by `ifup` or `ifdown`.

---

Like all configuration files' `man` pages, the manual for `/etc/network/interfaces` is in section 5, and you can easily get that with `man 5 interfaces` (or even with `man interfaces` if nothing like `interfaces` exists in any prior sections).

To get to the variable `IFACE` in one go, leverage the `LESS` environment variable (assuming your pager for `man` is `less`, which is the default):

```
LESS='+/^[[:blank:]]+IFACE' man 5 interfaces
```

Comment: I clearly know how to find the manpages as I linked to a web based version of them. What I didn't know is how $ indicates a variable in a configuration file and thus what I was looking for in the manpage.

Comment: `man 5 interfaces`, `man interfaces` or `LESS='+/^[[:blank:]]+IFACE' man 5 interfaces` all returns this error message `No manual entry for interfaces`